# LSTM neural network on Arduino 33 sense BLE using tensorflow lite

Tags: arduino, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I have train my LSTM network and deploy it on the Arduino but my problem is that as you know the input of the LSTM network is as follows (window length of the time series data),(features) in my case 256 window  length and 6 axis IMU data which means 2D input however all of the examples that I have seen are only 1D input

here is the Arduino code that used  to assign the model's input

input->data.f[0] =aX

and when trying to modify the code to fit my input dimension
(256,6) like this
input->data.f[0][0] =aX

I got this error
fall_detection:142:44: error: invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript
tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead][5] = (gZ + 2000.0) / 4000.0;

Comment: Could it be that you defined samplesRead as a float when it should have been an int?

Comment: even when I put an int value in place of samplesRead got the same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the tensor input data "manually" by digging in to the internal structure of the TF Lite tensor type. I would suggest using the API here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_c

In particular the code snippet here:

```
float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
// Fill `input`.
```

gives you the proper pointer. Then you can just cast the pointer for your actual data structure. Something like this:

```
input = reinterpret_cast<float *>(aX);
```

I see the potential for confusion for the 2D vs. 1D issue, but it is OK as long as the input tensor is properly shaped. If it has shape <256, 6> what this means is that the 1D sequence of float values will be "a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,b0,b1,..." where the "a" values are all six values of the first row, the "b" values are all six values of the next row and so on. The standard C convention for multi-dimension memory layout works this way. Unless there is something unusual about your `aX` object, it should be fine. If `aX` is not laid out in this fashion, you should copy the data so that it is in this layout.